# How can one put labels over an image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

This question is slightly different from [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz).

What I'm asking is how can I put a vertex label, at a particular point (x,y), on an image of a graph in TikZ?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0 <--What is this?] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=.5]{graph.png}};
    \node[???]{$v_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: I assume you mean [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)? The approach there can be used to place arbitrary objects on an image, not only for red rectangles on mushrooms.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to draw a label.

Comment: Is it just a node?

Comment: I think I figured it out:  `\node[shift={(1.0,0.3)}]{$v_1$};`

Answer (score 7):

You can place anything using this approach, not just rectangles.

To place text, you have to use `\node at (<coordinates>) {<text>};`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{mushrooms.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[
        x={(image.south east)},
        y={(image.north west)}
    ]
        \node [white, font=\bfseries] at (0.25,0.65) {$P(X|Y)$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]